# In VB.NET, which LINQ to SQL Left-Join method is best to use?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

**Is one of these VB.NET LINQ to SQL Left Join options superior to other?**

I'm not sure which to use.

**Method 1: Lambda**

```
Dim query = From A In DB.Product_Categories
            From B In DB.MasItems.Where(Function(x) CBool(x.itemkey = A.ItemKey)).DefaultIfEmpty
            Select A.Name
```

**Method 2: Group Join**

```
Dim query = From A In DB.Product_Categories
            Group Join B In DB.MasItems On B.itemkey Equals A.ItemKey Into X = Group
            From Y In X.DefaultIfEmpty
            Select A.Name()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated SQL is the same for both queries, so in LINQ to SQL it is really personal preference.

Comment: I ran both in linqpad against two tables in my current project and looked at the sql. before I did, I assumed method 1 would not result in an outer join, but it in fact did.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: This is true for LINQ to Objects.
I don't know about LINQ to SQL.

Method 2 is faster, since `GroupJoin` builds a hashtable internally.

Method 1 is `O(n2)`, since it needs to search all of `MasItems` for each category.

Comment: can you comment on the other answer? I'm not sure which is correct at this point as they contradict

Comment: @hamlin: I hadn't realized that you were talking about LINQ to SQL.  I don't know; you can check the generated SQL.